# Dump all the files in app/Resources/public/img to web/img

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

I am using Symfony and I want to dump all the images that are in app/Resources/public/img to web/img.

I tried the following in my config.yml file

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    assets:

        app_resources_img:
            inputs:
                - "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/public/img/*"
            output: "img/*"
```

However, the problem is that, even though the files are copied in the folder `/web/img`, the names are not good. Normally, I have the file `1.png`, `2.png` but in `/web/img` I get the following files:

```
app_resources_img
app_resources_img_part_1_1
app_resources_img_part_1_1
```

However, I would want to have

```
1.png
2.png
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Why does this have an HTML label?

Comment: Why not just do the symlinking, as it does Assetic itself?

Comment: I removed the HTML tag from this post since it has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: @Diodeus sorry about that !